# Django model unique_together on primary key and unique constraints

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model given below.

```py
class mc(models.Model):
    ap=models.CharField(max_length=50,primary_key=True)
    de=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    STATUS=models.CharField(max_length=12,default='Y')
    class Meta:
        unique_together=(("ap","de"),)
        db_table='mc'
```

I have written ap='1', de='2' to table mc.

```
+----+----+--------+
| ap | de | STATUS |
+----+----+--------+
| 1  | 2  | Y      |
+----+----+--------+
```

Then i have tried to write ap='1' and de='3' but its just overwritten the previous one. Now the table contains

```
+----+----+--------+
| ap | de | STATUS |
+----+----+--------+
| 1  | 3  | Y      |
+----+----+--------+
```

Then i tried to write ap='2',de='3' and its work. Since i have given unique_together, the compination of ap and de is not working.

But unique_together work if i haven't used 'primary_key' or 'unique' constraints on either of ap or de.

Will you please help me.? How to use unique_together on primary keys?

Actual problem is that ,i have another class mc1 which use a foreign key to the field ap.

```
class mc1(models.Model):                                                                                            

    test=models.ForeignKey(mc,on_delete=models.CASCADE,to_field='ap')
```

So mc.ap should be unique to define a foreignkey.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Django does not support multiple-column primary keys. It has been a [feature request](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/373) for several years. Each model [must have one primary key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields).

In your case, if `ap` is the primary key, then each value in `ap` must be unique. It is not possible to store both `(ap=1, de=2)` and `(ap=1, de=3)`.

Perhaps you could add another field as the primary key. Then you will be able to have `unique_together` for `('ap', 'de')`.

Comment: Yeah i have tried that too.  But i have another class childmc, in that i have a foreign key to the ap. When i do migrate it put some error saying "ap should be unique".

Comment: How can i overcome this issue? Any way to solve this by using signals?

Comment: You can either have foreign key to the actual primary key, or have two integer fields to store the `ap` and `de` values (but in this case you'll lose the constraint checking). I don't see how signals will help you.

Comment: Is ther any 3rd party module to do this

Comment: I haven't used any myself. A quick search brings up [django-composite-foreignkey](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-composite-foreignkey). There may be others.